# Dereferencing object of forward declared class

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I have class `Presenter` which which inherits from `ModelListener`.

```
class Model;

class ModelListener
{
public:
    ModelListener() : model(0) {}

    virtual ~ModelListener() {}

    void bind(Model* m) { model = m; }

protected:
    Model * model;
};
```

Also, I have an instance `Presenter presenter`. When I call `presenter->model->PrintName()` it, of course, does not compile since `model` is protected to `presenter`. But if I then further change `Model * model` to public like this

```
class Model;

class ModelListener
{
public:
    ModelListener() : model(0) {}

    virtual ~ModelListener() {}

    void bind(Model* m) { model = m; }

//protected:
    Model * model;
};
```

I do get:

> MyView.cpp: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Model'
>        presenter->model->PrintName(); 
>   ModelListener.hpp: error: forward declaration of 'class Model'.

Why I get this error when going `public` and not when `protected`?

Answer (score 0):

Because compiler first checks if the member is accessible prior to actually attempt to access it.

In the first case, member is protected, so inaccessible, then compiler reports an error before trying to access its content.

In the second case, member is public, so accessible; then compiler tries to access it and fails as it is incompletly defined.

Include in MyView.cpp the header where the `Model` class is defined (e.g. `#include "Model.hpp"`) to fix this error.